# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number

Tags: javascript, jquery

What is wrong with this code:

```
var car;
if($('input:radio[name=fahrzeug]:checked').val() == "Lamborghini Gallardo GT3") {
    car = 389;
}elseif($('input:radio[name=fahrzeug]:checked').val() == "Ferrari 430 Scuderia"){
    car = 349;
}else{
    car = 0;
}
```

Because I get this error: Uncaught SyntaxError: **Unexpected number**

Comment: What I get is `SyntaxError: Unexpected token {`.

Comment: @RuneFS I just started this question, and cant accept an answer following 12 minutes!

Comment: but you have ansked 54 questions of which you've only accepted an answer for 45% there's not much respect paid to those helping you in that and no coolness either...

Comment: @RuneFS thank you for your notice, I didnt know that it is so important! But I am going to review my questions and accept answers

Comment: Super not only does it show respect to the help given but more importantly it helps others with the same problem because they no which answer helped the most. Have a nice day

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no `elseif` keyword in JavaScript. Use `else if` instead.

**Reference:**

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else

Comment: Thank you @VisioN I didnt know that because I am used to php programming.

Comment: @TooCooL Languages are different. You're welcome.

Answer (score 3):

This's what's wrong:

```
elseif
```

That should be:

```
else if
```

Comment: Your hat looks perfectly suitable :D

Comment: @VisioN: But [bowties are cool](http://25.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_maq2sa0Yuh1rgctqqo1_400.png).
I didn't notice you beat me to the answer, good job!